# Computer is swapping out random characters in all OSes

Tags: ubuntu, usb

Weird PC problem that I do not understand:

My PC failed to boot Ubuntu, with a load of unrecognised characters shown on the screen.
In troubleshooting it, I tried running a different OSes (Enlightenment from a USB stick, MemTest86 from a USB stick) and saw the same behaviour, random characters swapped into the screen.

[Two screenshots](https://photos.app.goo.gl/rmNWSThBfb2LsNp27)

What the flip could be causing this?

Comment: Hmmm that's strange. Does this only happen when you run an OS or something from the USB?

Comment: Click on image icon when you edit your post and upload screenshots by following instructions then it would be displayed directly in your post and attract more people who might willing to help you.

Comment: That looks to me like a hardware issue. If you have some spare video card, you probably can try it. Also, is it happened when computer just started (is cold). Did Memtest86 passed all tests? Do you use internal (onboard) video or you using external video card ?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to bad video memory.

If this is an onboard graphics card, clean and reseat your RAM modules. Or identify and replace the bad module.

If it is an add-on video card, clean and reseat the card.

If this fails to resolve the issue you either have a bad motherboard (onboard video) or bad video card (add-on video).

Comment: Removing the add-on video card seems to have fixed it.
(Reseating it didn't help.)
I'll try cleaning the contacts and reseating it again. If that doesn't work I guess I'll bin the graphics card. It's quite an old MSI Nvidia N580GTX so heaven knows it's seen some action!